# Prevent text selection on tap and hold on iOS 13 / Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, ios13

Tapping and holding on a DIV causes Safari to select (i.e. highlight) the surrounding text and the phone to vibrate, even if this DIV has a `user-select` property set to `none`. This is very annoying in the context of my app. It seems to be specific to iOS 13 and its Haptic Touch.

I tried to `e.preventDefault()` on the `touchstart` event and it worked, but at the same time disabled scrolling capabilities.

I also tried to `e.preventDefault()` on the `webkitmouseforcewillbegin` event, as recommended in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/RespondingtoForceTouchEventsfromJavaScript.htm), but this didn't work at all.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Video: https://youtu.be/SstDm0M8RN0

Answer (score 3):

Calling `event.returnValue = false;` from all touch events (`touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove`, `touchcancel`) prevents from the surrounding text selection.
Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j_u_l_e_e/yLdt1s4o/

Comment: I applied this to my button component and it worked, on iOS 14

Comment: This solves our problem too in iOS 14, but am using an equivalent `event.preventDefault()` instead, because `event.returnValue` is deprecated per https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue and apparently so since maybe 2013.  A valuable answer nevertheless.